# Strength of a survey based of a sample size of 70% of whole population

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, standard-deviation, confidence-interval

Let's say we have a marketing company taking a survey on a population N on each of the 50 states. The marketing company tells the statistician that they will send two samples, one with 70% of the polls and then the rest of the polls.

The poll is simple, which product does the population prefer: **Product A**, **Product B**, **Product C**. The total sampling is 10,000 surveys for each state (N=10000). For simplicity's sake we will only take into consideration three states:

**70% of the polls computed (so 7,000 for each state)**

```
Florida
Product A: 42%
Product B: 38%
Product C: 20%
New York
Product A: 53%
Product B: 40%
Product C: 7%
California
Product A: 55%
Product B: 40%
Product C: 5%
```

Now, the marketing company asks a simple question. If the the **remaining 30%** (the rest is 3,000 surveys for each state) is computed, how is each product's percentage expected to change foe each state? (what range +/-, stdv maybe?, so how do we calculate the standard deviation?)

So summarizing... The marketing company wants to know one thing: **"Is the outcome expected to change or stay the same after the rest of the surveys are computed?"** Can we assume that 7,000 is a good estimate of the whole population considering the TOTAL population (of people that tried the three products) is 10,000?

Comment: Is it 60/40 as you say at first, or 70/30 as you say later? Is the assumption that _population_ proportions favoring Products A, B, C have not changed between the two installments?

Comment: Sorry, just fixed it, it's 70%. Basically the marketing company wants to know one thing: "Is the outcome expected to change or stay the same after the rest of the surveys are computed?" considering that they are *randomly* taken, so it's impossible to know if the proportions change. However, can we assume that 7,000 is a good estimate of the whole population considering the TOTAL population is 10,000?

Comment: The difference between sample proportions for 10,000 respondents should not be greatly different than sample proportions for 7000, provided all are sampled from the same population. You don't say whether you are testing a null hypothesis (such as $H_0: p = (.5, .4, .1)$ vs $H_a: p \ne (.5, .4, .1),$ or whether you are getting estimates of the $p_i$ with confidence intervals for each. With the test you will have somewhat  better power with $n = 10000$ than with $n = 7000;$ also the larger sample size will give somewhat shorter confidence intervals. // Your procedure & purpose are unclear.